# UITabBar image to UITabBarItem with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, storyboard

I have `UITabBarController` with `UITabBar` which has three `UITabBarItem`.
Project is with storyboard. How can I set different image to each `UITabBarItem`?

I want do something like this:

`TabBarItem1 -> image1_unselected and image1_selected`

`TabBarItem1 -> image2_unselected and image2_selected`

`TabBarItem1 -> image3_unselected and image3_selected`

**EDIT:**

Probably I didn't write precisely, but I want set custom image and make `UITabbar` with custom graphics. Something like `UITabbar` in "Find My Friends" app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found solution.

At the beginning of `viewDidLoad` in my `firsTabBarViewController.m`  I added this code:

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn1_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn1.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn2_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn2.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn3_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barBtn3.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
```

And now I have exactly what I want in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`TabBar` images are 32x32 points or smaller and are automatically styled by iOS to appear in a `monochromatic` color scheme (regardless of what you choose). Simple line drawings with a transparent background turn out the best when creating your tab bar interface art.

It is done by first adding the image resource to your project.

Then click on the `TabBarItem` you wish to edit, and go to the attributes inspector (`Alt + Cmd + 4`)

Then change the '`Identifier`' to '`Custom`'

Finally, select your image from the Image dropdown.

Comment: Probably I didn't write precisely, but I want set custom image and make uitabbar with custom graphics. Something like uitabbar in "Find My Friends" app.

Comment: Well Apple like to keep things consistent, so to customise it in the way you want to, you have to create your own custom TabBar. Have a look at these tutorials - http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/ & http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in each  `viewcontroller`.

-> In `initwithnibname`....; method

`self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];`

Answer (score 0):

**murzynpl** answer is correct, but you can also do this by adding the following code in `AppDelegate.m` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";
tabBarItem2.title = @"Favorites";

NSString *tabOneImage = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *tabOneImageSelected = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *tabTwoImage = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *tabTwoImageSelected = [[NSString alloc] init];

if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480.0f) {
    tabOneImageSelected = @"home_icon_selected-568h@2x.png";
    tabTwoImageSelected = @"fav_icon_selected-568h@2x.png";
    tabOneImage = @"home_icon-568h@2x.png";
    tabTwoImage = @"fav_icon-568h@2x.png";
}
else {
    tabOneImageSelected = @"home_icon_selected.png";
    tabTwoImageSelected = @"fav_icon_selected.png";
    tabOneImage = @"home_icon.png";
    tabTwoImage = @"fav_icon.png";
}


[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tabOneImageSelected]
          withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tabOneImage]];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tabTwoImageSelected]
          withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tabTwoImage]];
```